# How to get additional scope data using next-auth?

Tags: javascript, oauth, next.js, next-auth

I am using next-auth with discord authentication, I added the guilds to my scope but I am not able to get the guild data, how can this be done?

```js
const options = {
  providers: [
    Providers.Discord({
      clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope: "identify guilds",
    }),
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 13):

Most recent build lets you override any pattern (deeply merged so that you only have to type the fields you wish to update).

Came here looking for this exact answer, and this is what I used:

```js
DiscordProvider({
  clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
  authorization: { params: { scope: 'identify guilds' } },
}),
```

Comment: thanks @BadPirate But you can't have two providers with the same name, so expanding scope incrementally doesn't work right?

I have copied the Google Provider into another file, imported it and changed the ID and scope in that provider.... after the user logs in, i show the a button with the signin method calling the second provider.  I think it's working but how do i check the scope?

Answer (score 9):

Also ran into this using the Discord OAuth2.
I found it in NextAuth's docs here:

https://next-auth.js.org/providers/discord#example

Basically, you add scope as a general option after the provider array.

```
import DiscordProvider from "next-auth/providers/discord";
...
providers: [
  DiscordProvider({
    clientId: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.DISCORD_CLIENT_SECRET,
    authorization: { params: { scope: 'identify guilds' } },
  })
]
...
```

Comment: Link is dead, and answer seems outdated.

Comment: @BadPirate updated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for scopes for different Providers (Google, Facebook, ...), the scope key is not necessarily always at the same place, so be sure to look at your provider's doc on the Next-Auth website: https://next-auth.js.org/providers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33267416)